# How to put labels to current buttons on mui-datatables

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I have a mui-datatables install on a React app, and its working fine, but I would like to put labels on the side of the sort and search buttons, how could I do that? thanks.[image: screenshot]

My current options object:

```
const options = {
    resizableColumns: true,
    selectableRows: "none",
    responsive: "standard",
    print: false,
    download: false,
    viewColumns: false,
   ...
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how can add it specifically, but you can add a Tooltip instead of that. For example:

```
const options = {
    ...
    textLabels: {
        toolbar: {
          search: "Search",
        },
         
    },
};
```

Adding this code above, when the user passes the mouse over the Search Icon, the user will see the text "Search". It is not exactly the same as you asked, but I hope to help you!

Obs: with `TextLabels` you can personalize a lot of things on your table. For example:

```
textLabels: {
    body: {
      noMatch: "No match",
      toolTip: "Order by",
      columnHeaderTooltip: (column) => `Order by ${column.label}`,
    },
    pagination: {
      next: "Next page",
      previous: "Previous page",
      rowsPerPage: "Rows per page:",
      displayRows: "of",
    },
    toolbar: {
      search: "Search",
    },
    selectedRows: {
      text: "Row selected",
    },
    viewColumns: {
      title: "Show columns",
      titleAria: "Show/hide columns",
    },
  },
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I'm using tooltips and custom text labels, but its not what i require, what I need is to add text labels to those existing buttons.